# Foreign Key is incorrectly formed - Laravel8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using mysql database. I have two table Schemas (Client and Product Models) with a One to Many relationship.

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('job');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained();
        $table->string('productName')->unique();
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->float('unitPrice');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I also tried to use the syntax below instead of

```
` $table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained();`
```

but I get the same ERROR.

```
`$table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');
 $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');`
```

Here's the error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `product`.`products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: 
alter table `products` add constraint `products_client_id_foreign` foreign key (`client_id`) references `clients` (`id`))
```

Comment: Are the migrations running in the correct order?

Comment: I just noticed that products migration is triggered first ! Thank you for spotting that. But how can I change the migrations order ?

Comment: Rename your products migration file so that the timestamp at the end of the filename is later than the timestamp on your clients migration.

Comment: Thanks a lot Unflux ! Appreciate your help